# How to import NGONS from Lightwave to Blender?

Tags: objects, external-applications

I don't want meshes to be triangulated. Is there a way to keep Ngons when importing objects from Lightwave into Blender

Answer (score 1):

By default, the OBJ file exported from Lightwave supports N-gons.
When importing it into Blender, it will import Ngons by default. Make sure it is enabled in the Import Window:

[image]